# How to implement a slight change on source file in a docker project?

Tags: c#, docker, docker-compose

I am real newbie in docker. I have a docker based project. The project is coded in C#, has multi-containers and use docker-compose.

The project is running in the server.
I just want to modify one c# source file in one container.
I want to know, after I modify that file, do I need to build the project agian? or just execute

```
docker-compose down
docker-compose up -d
```

Thanks

Is this the correct process？

1. Modify the source file.
2. `docker-compose down`
3. `docker-compose up --force-recreate --build -d`
4. `docker image prune -f`

Comment: _I just want to modify one c# source file in one container_ Your source code is in the container, or your project is deployed to the container?

Comment: the source code is in the container

Comment: Assuming you're using .NET core with Linux containers (I assume the recommendation applies to Windows containers also), the general guidance is to have a multi-layer container build process. You define a _build_ layer with the .NET core SDK and that container is responsible for building the project and outputting the build artifacts. Those artifacts are then copied to a _runtime_ layer which only contains what's necessary at runtime for the project. The defacto docker [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/samples/dotnetcore/) has a good working example. The container will need to be built...

Comment: ...before pushing it to the (or your private) registry and then pulled to the docker host.

Comment: Of course, each layer is separated by `FROM` statements in your dockerfile as illustrated in the documentation